# Hibernate: param index out of range when removing element from unidirectional OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, jpa-2.0, playframework-1.x

After looking up an instance of `Book` -- when I try to remove an element from `book.genres` and then call `book.save()`, I get the following exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).

From hibernate logs:

> 2016-12-08 12:28:53,584 DEBUG ~ update book_genres set book_id=null where     book_id=? and genre=? 2016-12-08 12:28:53,585 TRACE ~ binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 7 2016-12-08 12:28:53,585 TRACE ~ binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 7 2016-12-08 12:28:53,585 TRACE ~ binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - 5

Note that both look ups and inserting into elements into `book.genres` work fine from the `Book` entity. When looking up a `Book`, all the appropriate genres are retrieved.  When inserting a new `Genre` entity into `book.genres`, the update is propagated to the database.

It is only that deletes that seem to be having a problem.

Book entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book extends GenericModel implements IBook{
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Set<models.books.Genre> genres = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Genre entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book_genres")
public class Genre extends GenericModel{
    @Embeddable
    private static final class Id implements Serializable{
        @Column(name = "book_id", nullable = false)
        private long bookId;
        @Column(name = "genre")
        private int genre;

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o){
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode(){
            ...
        }
    }

    @javax.persistence.Id
    private Id id;

    public Genre(long bookId, IBook.Genre genre){
        Id id = new Id();
        id.bookId = bookId;
        id.genre = genre.getCode();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Genre(){

    }

    public Genre getGenre(){
        return IBook.Genre.fromId(id.genre, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        ...
    }
}
```

IBook.java

```
public interface IBook{
    enum Genre{
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: To my understanding, version 4.2.19.  I'm using play framework version 1.4, which has dependencies on hibernate-core-4.2.19.Final.jar and associated jars